# IP address/network parsing from text file using python

Tags: python, regex, ip

I have the below text file that I would need some help with parsing out IP addresses.

The text file is of the form

```
abc 10.1.1.1/32   aabbcc
def 11.2.0.0/16   eeffgg
efg 0.0.0.0/0   ddeeff
```

In other words, a bunch of IP networks exist as part of a log file. The output should be provided as below:

```
10.1.1.1/32
11.2.0.0/16
0.0.0.0/0
```

I have the below code but does not output the required information

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
for eachline in file.readlines():
    ip_regex = re.findall(r'(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}', eachline)
    print ip_regex
```

Comment: Try to describe what does each line of code and you will find the error. see re documentation too.

Comment: Well, you didn't include anything in your regex to match the `/32` or similar at the end, so of course it's only going to match the `10.1.1.1` or similar.

Comment: `re.findall("\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\/\d+",file.read())`, you should also use `with` to open your files

Comment: As a side note, there is no reason to use `readlines()` there. `file` is already an iterable of lines. All you're doing is wastefully forcing Python to read and parse the entire file in memory before you can use it.

Comment: As another side note, those aren't IP addresses, those are IP _networks_, which contain an address and a bitmask. In fact, your existing code is _already_ finding the IP addresses that are part of those networks…

Comment: @abarnert you are right...a bit sloppy with the IP terminology in the question...should be IP networks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your regex doesn't even attempt to capture anything but four dotted numbers, so of course it's not going to match anything else, like a `/32` on the end. if you just add, e.g., `/\d{1,2}` to the end, it'll fix that:

```
(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/\d{1,2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7bQpjvtFIqCLPck1)

---

However, if you don't understand regular expressions well enough to understand that, you probably shouldn't be using a regex as a piece of "magic" that you'll never be able to debug or extend. It's a bit more verbose with `str` methods like `split` or `find`, but maybe easier to understand for a novice:

```
for line in file:
    for part in line.split()
        try:
            address, network = part.split('/')
            a, b, c, d = address.split('.')
        except ValueError:
            pass # not in the right format
        else:
            # do something with part, or address and network, or whatever
```

---

As a side note, depending on what you're actually doing with these things, you might want to use the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module (or [the backport on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress/1.0.6) for 2.6-3.2) rather than string parsing:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> s = '10.1.1.1/32'
>>> a = ipaddress.ip_network('10.1.1.1/32')
```

You can combine that with either of the above:

```
for line in file:
    for part in line.split():
        try:
            a = ipaddress.ip_network(part)
        except ValueError:
            pass # not the right format
        else:
            # do something with a and its nifty methods
```

Comment: this website Debuggex that @abernert linked to, is the best website for regex i have ever seen.

Comment: @TehTris: Yeah, I do love it. But notice that once they're out of beta, they're apparently going to start charging for non-JS regexes. They already started charging for the convert-to-plain-English feature (which they then disabled…). Very clever; I'm not sure I could go back to… whatever I used to use, which I can't even remember anymore. :)

Comment: ipaddress does not work for adresses like this "010.200.074.104". To parse this, it is better to use a one-liner like this: ".".join([str(int(x)) for x in ipv4_str.split(".")])

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, a regex might be overkill, you could use `split`

```
with open(filename) as f:
    ipList = [line.split()[1] for line in f]
```

This should produce a list of strings, which are the ip addresses.