# Python Regex to identify IPv4 address from string

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, ip

I am kindof stuck in extracting an IPv4 address from a String.

---

My input string & constraints are as follows :

- IPv4 Range : `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`
- IPv4 address may / may not be present in the string

  - Valid Examples :  `this is an ip` & `this is an ip 200.100.2.32`
- String may start with IPv4 address

  - Valid Examples : `200.100.2.32 is an ip` | Output : `['200.100.2.32']`
  - Invalid Examples : `200.100.2.32is an ip` | Output : `[]`
- String may end with IPv4 address

  - Valid Examples : `the ip is 200.100.2.32` | Output : `['200.100.2.32']`
  - Invalid Examples : `the ip is200.100.2.32` | Output : `[]`
- String may contain an IPv4 address in the middle, and if it does - there will a space before and after the IPv4 address.

  - Valid Examples : `the ip is 200.100.2.32 and it is ipv4` | Output : `['200.100.2.32']`
  - Valid Examples : `the ip is 200.100.2.32and it is ipv4` | Output : `[]`
- Multiple IPs may be present in a single string

  - Valid Examples : `200.100.2.32 100.50.1.16` | Output : `['200.100.2.32', '100.50.1.16']`
  - Invalid Examples : `200.100.2.32.100.50.1.16` | Output : `[]`

---

I am trying to build a regex for the above cases, they look fairly straightforward, and I am not able to incorporate all the regex checks.

I have been referring to the answers on these links : [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327912/python-parse-ipv4-addresses-from-string-even-when-censored), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370321/ip-address-network-parsing-from-text-file-using-python), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890896/extract-ip-address-from-an-html-string-python)

---

Can someone help me in the right direction? To Summarize :

- IPv4 will have a space before it or starts at the begining of the string
- IPv4 will have a space after it or finishes at the end of the string
- IPv4 obeys the range : `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`

---

Code

```
def find_ip(str) :
    ip_pattern = re.compile('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s') # need to strengthen the regex here
    ip = re.findall(ip_pattern, str)
    return ip
```

Comment: What code have you written?

Comment: adding the code to this in a min. making the edit.

Comment: Would the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module help you here? `split` the string and `try` calling [`IPv4Adress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address) on each string from the split.

Comment: You've got the IP address done.  Now it's just regex stuff.  You need 0 or more of them, it can occur at the beginning of the string or after a blank, etc.  Personally, I would make a separate regex for each of these cases and alternate them, but I'm no regex wizard!

Comment: @saulspatz - You don't need multiple regexes...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - i was trying to solve this multiple regexes. Is there anyway to to simplify/sysnthesise this to a single regex?

Comment: I don't see anything to simplify. Just use the expression in the linked duplicate, and it'll find any IP address, wherever it appears in a string.

Answer (score 2):

The regex:

```
(?:^|\b(?<!\.))(?:1?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:1?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}(?=$|[^\w.])
```

An [example](https://regex101.com/r/dW4nA5/1) of matches.